# How to get Twitter Followers Number jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter

please tell me how can i get twitter followers number in jQuery
and please give me also demo
with full detail

Comment: same like How to do magic with jQuery.

Comment: i'm making a widget for blogger that's why i posted this question

Comment: is your blog -->rafaysoft ??

Comment: rafaysoft and rafaytutorials both are my blogs

Comment: so, you're building a blogger widget, and asking us to do it for you? basically?

Comment: no i just want to know how to get twitter followers count in jquery

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5025)

> Twitter don't support or recommend performing OAuth directly through Javascript -- it's insecure and puts your application at risk. The only acceptable way to perform it is if you kept all keys and secrets server-side, computed the OAuth signatures and parameters server side, then issued the request client-side from the server-generated OAuth values.

Read [Working with javascript in old api](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/jquery-get-total-twitter-followers.html) not work now and [How to get Oath key](http://www.slideshare.net/Tweetganic/generate-twitter-applications).